# values not defined while saving file in csv format in js and json,what is the issue?

Tags: javascript, json

```
<button id="mybutton">Download</button>
```

---

```
const objectToCsv = function(data){

    const csvRows = [];

    //get the headers
        const headers = Object.keys(data[0]);
        csvRows.push(headers.join(','));
        //console.log(headers);


    //Loop over the rows
    for(const row of data) {
        const values = headers.map(header => {
            const escaped = (''+row[header]).replace(/"/g,'\\"');
            return '"${escaped}"';

        });

        csvRows.push(values.join(','));

        //console.log(values.join(','));
    }

    return csvRows.join('\n');

    //console.log(csvRows);

};

const download = function(data){
    const blob = new Blob([data],{type:'text/csv'});
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('hidden', '');
    a.setAttribute('href',url);
    a.setAttribute('download', 'download.csv');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);

};

const getReport = async function(){
    const jsonUrl = 'https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/NJmmhK3pV';
    const res = await fetch(jsonUrl);
    const json = await res.json();

    const data = json.map(row => ({
        age: row.age,
        email: row.email,
        firstname: row.name.first,
        lastname: row.name.last
    }));

    //console.log(data);

    const csvData = objectToCsv(data);
    download(csvData);
};

(function(){

    //button click
    const button = document.getElementById('mybutton');
    button.addEventListener('click', getReport);

})();
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: If you uncomment console.log(data); what is displayed?

Comment: There's no `undefined` anywhere : https://jsfiddle.net/bsL379c8/

Comment: @SPlatten : in console.log(data) all the values in the link was getting displayed